# What is cocktail MC sample in physics analysis?

Tags: thermodynamics, particle-physics, experimental-physics, terminology, computational-physics

In high energy physics, when scientists make a physics analysis, sometimes they use cocktail Monte Carlo sample to study signal and background shape.
But I just know what inclusive or exclusive MC sample is.
I have not idea what Cocktail MC stands for.
Here is a sample where cocktail MC is used in a Physics analysis:

[image: Here is a sample where cocktail MC is used in a Physics analysis.]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are reading some internal documentation – this type of jargon usually does not get into publications, or is explained explicitly.

In this case, the term "cocktail" most likely refers to "a mixture of different processes with predefined fractions of each of them". For example, if one knows the expected composition of backgrounds and the (relative) rates of each background process, one can simulate all of these backgrounds in one go producing such "cocktail" simulated dataset.

This approach is not truly "inclusive" as not all possible processes are simulated, but only predefined ones, that's probably why they call it "semi-exclusive" in your example.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I find the cocktail MC is a kind of simulation which contains  more than one decay mode in a sample.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.